# using Darboux's theorem to prove the derivative of $f$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f$ : $[0,2]$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb R$ is continuous on $[0,2]$ and differentiable on $(0,2)$, and that $f(0)$ = $0$, $f(1)=1$ and $f(2)=1$.

Show that there exists $c \in (0,2)$ such that $f'(c) = {\frac{1}{3}} $.

Note: This question is from "Introduction to Real Analysis" by Bartle & Sherbert ex 6.2 qn 20, that I'm using for practice.

Comment: First, apply the mean Value Theorem to $f$ on $[0,1]$ and on $[1,2]$.

Answer (score 1):

By the MVT we find $x_1\in (0,1), x_2\in (1,2)$ with $f'(x_1)=1, f'(x_2)=0$. By Darboux's Theorem, there is $c\in (x_1,x_2)$ with $f'(c)=\frac 13$.

Comment: i could get $X_1$ and $X_2$ but i can't get 1/3

Comment: Darboux's Theorem says: If $f$ is differentiable on an open interval $I$ and $[x_1,x_2]\subseteq I$, then for every $\eta$ with  $\eta\in (f'(x_1),f'(x_2))$ resp. $(f'(x_2),f'(x_1))$ there exists $c\in (x_1,x_2)$ such that $f'(c)=\eta$. Apply this to $I=(0,2), \eta=1/3$.

Comment: Does it mean that as long as the value is in between $0$ and $1$, it can be $f'(c)$? for example, $1/4$ instead of $1/3$?